# Python and tomcat on the same machine

Tags: java, python, tomcat7, apache

using sec-web httpd.
the python code has api: host/v0/auth/sessions/blablba...
the java code has api: host/v0/auth/users/blabla....
there is a conf file on the machine which have the following for the python api:

```
 ProxyPass                    /v0/auth/sessions http://localhost:8098/v0/auth/sessions
 ProxyPassReverse     /v0/auth/sessions http://localhost:8098/v0/auth/sessions
```

and for the java api:

```
ProxyPass               /   ajp://localhost:8009/
ProxyPassReverse        /   ajp://localhost:8009/
```

now:
when I'm accessing the python api I'm getting good response, but when trying to access the java api I/m getting '[]' - the status code is 200 but I'm supposed to get a different response.

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar task and I put into the config for java application the following apache config file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin "mail@example.com"
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com`

    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPreserveHost on

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    <Location />
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Please note that http://example.com:8080/ opens java application. It is not http://example.com:8080/app/. Java application placed in the root of /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ dir as ROOT.jar (as for my tomcat).

Comment: I try the following but without any luck, the original conf start with:<VirtualHost *>
so I think every thing is going to the python api

Comment: Yes, every thing is going but proxy redirects requests to the another path (which is described in the conf, http://127.0.0.1:8080/)

Answer (score 0):

In our server, we run Apache as proxy server and here is the sample, I hope it would help you.

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On


<Proxy http://localhost:8080/service>
        AddDefaultCharset off
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Proxy http://localhost:8080/foo>
        AddDefaultCharset off
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Proxy>


<Location "/service">

    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all

    ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/service
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/service
</Location>

<Location "/foo">

    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all

    ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/foo
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/foo
</Location>

</IfModule>
```